# In which context can an emitted file have no or multiple sources?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Rollup plugin and am using the program API to compile source files.

I deduce from the `writeFileCallback` of the `Program::emit` definition that is possible for an emitted file to have 0 to n source files:

```
emit(targetSourceFile?: SourceFile, writeFile?: WriteFileCallback, cancellationToken?: CancellationToken, emitOnlyDtsFiles?: boolean, customTransformers?: CustomTransformers): EmitResult;

type WriteFileCallback = (fileName: string, text: string, writeByteOrderMark: boolean, onError?: (message: string) => void, sourceFiles?: readonly SourceFile[], data?: WriteFileCallbackData) => void;
```

In `WriteFileCallback`, source files type is `sourceFiles?: readonly SourceFile[]`, hence it can:

- not be present (i.e. consist of no source at all)
- consist of multiple sources

I'd like to implement tests that cover these two situations; in which context can they happen?

Comment: Compiling multiple files into one (bundling), or creating a file out of nothing like adding a metadata file about the output.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was not possible to create bundles with TypeScript - if so we would not need bundlers to begin with. Am I missing something? About the metadata thing, I'll try to find a way to cover this situation. Do you know of some online example on how to achieve this?